# Designing Multi Floor Architectural Layouts

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, reference-request, multi-objective-optimization

Architectural layouts define the position and shape of rooms in 3D space, where windows and water pipes are and as well as how humans travel between rooms (among other things). There is a lot of research based on floor plans (having all rooms defined by $x,y$ coordinates only). "Mixed integer programming model with non-circular and guided constraints for architectural layout design optimization" by Kamol and Krung is a good introduction. "MIQP-based Layout Design for Building Interiors" by Wu et al proposes to design multiple floors at the same time and enforce consistency of space planned for stairs between levels. This assumes that all rooms are at a few fixed $z$ coordinates.

**I am looking for formulations or literature where rooms are allocated as 3d objects to verify the assumption that treating things based on different floors is a justified simplification in my use case.**

Formulations from other applied areas which allocates non overlapping cuboids with "connections" between some of them which impose constrains on the coordinates of the connected cuboids are also welcome in so far as they can be adapted for what i want.

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit more on what you are looking for? Are you looking for a mathematical formulation to create or optimize floor layout? or some of the architecting software you mean?

Comment: I am looking for a **formulation** to create an optimized room placement that is free to plan in the height component or literature that discusses such a formulation or literature that discusses the tradeoff between planning in floors with consistency conditions vs allocating freely in 3d space. What make you think of i am looking for architectural software solution?

Comment: From a practical point of view, many of the plant layout that has been created by the optimization model cannot handle the real situation limitation. For example, suppose you want to plant some flexible rooms in the rectangle area that has parallel Pillars. Many of the OP cannot make a good feasible plan. In contrast, by architectural software, I know that some of them have an optimization engine to create a good plan based on some real limitations, you can easily handle that. As far as I know, some 3-dimensional bin packing models can produce a multi-level layout plan. Have you tried that?

Comment: Bin packing is usually done with fixed size packages and not flexible sized rooms but if you have some literature which allocates non overlapping cuboids with "connections" between some of them which impose constraints on the coordinates of the connected cuboids that would be an acceptable solution too. I have only seen bin packing literature with fixed sized cuboids which is not what i want.

Comment: Does what you mentioned as `flexible sized room` mean unequal shape?

Comment: I want to allocate non overlaping cubiods. But the dimensions of the cuboids beforehand is not know or fixed.